# Take Plot Data and Turn Into Animation

Tags: matlab, animation, plot

I have written code that simulates the rolling of a triangle and gives the output as a trace plot of the three vertices and the centroid for a specified number of rotations.

I would like to turn this plot into an animation and add a circle at each of the triangle vertices to represent wheels.

Can anyone suggest an efficient method to do this?

I am looking to make an animation something like this, except in my case I am not using a ruleaux traingle and just need an animation, not something interactive: 
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ARollingReuleauxTriangle/

```
close all
clear

%functions to create rigid body transform matrix---------------------------
hat = @(w) [0,-w(3),w(2); w(3),0,-w(1); -w(2),w(1),0];  
rotMatrix = @(th,w) eye(3) + hat(w)*sind(th) + hat(w)*hat(w)*(1-cosd(th));
rbTrans = @(th,w,q) [rotMatrix(th,w), (eye(3) - rotMatrix(th,w))*q(1:3); 0 0 0 1];
%arguments: th=rotation angle, w=rotation axis, q=center of rotation (column vector)

nTurns=5;
degPerTurn=120; %degrees
nStepsPerTurn=1000; %resolution of each "turn". number of points

d = 5.2; %distance from centroid to a vertex
r = 4;
w = [0;0;1;0]; %rotation vector=z-axis
X0 = [0;0;0]; %initial position of centroid

%initialize vertices
v=[0;1;0];
p1 = X0 + [0;d;0];
p2 = X0 + d*rotMatrix(-120,w)*v;
p3 = X0 + d*rotMatrix(120,w)*v;
P(1,1,:) = p1;
P(2,1,:) = p2;
P(3,1,:) = p3;
P(4,1,:) = X0;

rotVertex=2;
thStep=-degPerTurn/nStepsPerTurn;
for i=1:nTurns
    for j=1:nStepsPerTurn
        %center of rotation
        q = squeeze(P(rotVertex,end,:));
        q = q + [0; -r; 0];

        %transform is a rotation of 120/nSteps about z-axis centered at a
        %particular vertex
        g = rbTrans(thStep, w, q);

        I=size(P,2)+1; %add new element by inserting to (end+1)
        for k=1:size(P,1) %for each point we're following-- vertices and centroid
            pt = g*[squeeze(P(k,I-1,:)); 1]; %apply transform to last existing value of this point
            P(k,I,:) = pt(1:3); %and add it to the end
        end
    end

    %vertices are numbered clockwise around the triangle
    rotVertex=rotVertex-1;
    if rotVertex<1
        rotVertex=rotVertex+3;
    end
end

%extract data from 3D array
P1=squeeze(P(1,:,:));
P2=squeeze(P(2,:,:));
P3=squeeze(P(3,:,:));
C=squeeze(P(4,:,:));

figure
plot(P1(:,1),P1(:,2),'b'),hold on
plot(P2(:,1),P2(:,2),'r')
plot(P3(:,1),P3(:,2),'g')
plot(C(:,1),C(:,2),'k')
xlabel('Horizontal Distance (inches)')
ylabel('Vertical Distance (inches)')
axis equal
legend('Vertex 1','Vertex 2','Vertex 3','Centroid', 'Location','Best')

figure
subplot(4,1,1),plot(P1(:,1),P1(:,2)),axis equal,ylabel('P1')
subplot(4,1,2),plot(P2(:,1),P2(:,2)),axis equal,ylabel('P2')
subplot(4,1,3),plot(P3(:,1),P3(:,2)),axis equal,ylabel('P3')
subplot(4,1,4),plot(C(:,1),C(:,2)),axis equal,ylabel('C')
xlabel('Horizontal Distance (inches)')

figure
plot(P3(:,1),P3(:,2),'b'),hold on
plot(C(:,1),C(:,2),'k')
axis equal
xlabel('Horizontal Distance (inches)')
ylabel('Vertical Distance (inches)')
legend('Vertex 3','Centroid', 'Location','Best')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encapsulate the drawing of your points in a `for` loop, drawing each triple of points individually then placing a `pause` command for a few milliseconds accompanied with a `drawnow`.  If you want this to be an animation, I'm assuming you only want to show one triangle per "frame", and so what you can do is when you want to plot the next set of points, take the previous points and plot them as white to artificially clear them without clearing the entire frame.

Do something like this.  Bear in mind I'm only targeting the code where I think is where you want the animation to occur:

```
figure;
for i = 1 : size(P1, 1)
    if (i > 1)
         plot(P1(i-1,1), P1(i-1,2), 'w.', P2(i-1,1), P2(i-1,2), 'w.', ...
              P3(i-1,1), P3(i-1,2), 'w.', C(i-1,1), C(i-1,2), 'w.');
    end

    plot(P1(i,1), P1(i,2), 'b.', P2(i,1), P2(i,2), 'r.', ...
         P3(i,1), P3(i,2), 'g.', C(i,1), C(i,2), 'k.');
    axis equal;
    xlabel('Horizontal Distance (inches)');
    ylabel('Vertical Distance (inches)');
    legend('Vertex 1','Vertex 2','Vertex 3','Centroid', 'Location','Best');
    drawnow;
    pause(0.1); %// Pause for 0.1 seconds
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I incorporate that in my code, I seem to get a sort of strobe light effect. I keep getting "Warning: Plot empty," and the graph keeps popping up and flashing the plot key and axes but no figure.

Comment: OK, I'm going to try something else.  I've edited my code.  Try that and see what happens.  I don't have MATLAB where I am so I'm doing this all by faith :)  I've also made the pause longer so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Oh, I see! Well thank you for your help. It seems to be doing the same thing but slower. The plot doesn't seem to be being created.

Comment: That's weird... it should work.  If no one else has solved this problem, I'll get back to it when I get to a computer with MATLAB on Sunday (May 11, 2014) night... else, stay tuned!

Comment: Thank you very much! I greatly appreciate the help. Do you have any idea how to add circles to the triangle vertices and connect them all to the centroid?

Comment: Open circles? Try doing `plot(x,y,'o','MarkerSize',13);`. You want the circles slightly bigger than the vertices itself.  You can also draw lines using the `line` command.  I can't really give you more until I have MATLAB to try out all of this but this will get you started.

Comment: I edited my code. I simply had to change the markers so that it has `.`.  Not placing this in would default to drawing a line and that's not what you want.  However, this is **painfully** slow.  It takes about half a second to draw each frame.  I'll research some alternatives, but until then hope you find what you're looking for.